# Build a Bijective function to show that $\left |(0,1) \right | = \left |(1,2)\cup (3,4) \right |$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I would love to get some insight and explanation on how to build such function.
Thanks alot.

Comment: it's easy to get a bijection from $(0,\frac12)\cup(\frac12,1)$ to $(1,2)\cup(3,4)$; map $\frac12$ to something, map what was mapped to that to something else, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build it in pieces.

Can you map $\left(0,\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\cup \left(\dfrac{1}{2},1\right) \mapsto (1,2)\cup (3,4)$?

Once you have that, you just need to figure out what to do with $\dfrac{1}{2}$. How about for all $1+\dfrac{1}{n} \in \left(1,2\right), n\in \mathbb{N}$, you send $1+\dfrac{1}{n} \mapsto 1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Now, you can send $\dfrac{1}{2}\mapsto 1+\dfrac{1}{2}$ Basically, that second mapping frees up $1+\dfrac{1}{2}$ as a destination.

Comment: So defining:
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+3+\frac{1}{n+1} & 0<x<0.5\;or\;0.5<x<1\quad and\;x=\frac{1}{n}\;for\;n\in\mathbb{N}\\
x+3 & 0<x<0.5\;or\;0.5<x<1\quad and\;x\neq\frac{1}{n}\;for\;n\in\mathbb{N}\\
x=0.5 & 1.5
\end{cases}  $

is enough?

Comment: Your function is not a bijection.

Comment: How about this. $$f:\left(0,\dfrac{1}{2}\right) \to (1,2), f(x) = 1+2x \\ g:\left(\dfrac{1}{2},1\right) \to (3,4), g(x) = 2+2x \\ h:\left\{1+\dfrac{1}{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \to \left\{1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}, h\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) = 1+\dfrac{1}{n+1} \\ k:(0,1) \to (1,2)\cup (3,4), k(x) = \begin{cases}g(x), & 0.5 < x \\ 1.5, & x = 0.5 \\ h(f(x)), & x = \dfrac{1}{2n}, n\in \mathbb{N}, n>1 \\ f(x), & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Your bijection would be $k(x)$.

Comment: I found the conditions for when to use $h(f(x))$ by saying $1+2x =1+ \dfrac{1}{n} \Longrightarrow x = \dfrac{1}{2n}$.