# Show that the cardinalities of $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)\cup (3,4)$ are the same

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to show that $|(0,1)|=|(1,2)\cup(3,4)|$. I tried to define the function $f:(0,1)\to(1,2)\cup(3,4)$ by 
$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x+1 & x\in(0,\frac{1}{2}) 
\\ 2x+2 & x\in[\frac{1}{2},1)
\end{cases}$. Problem is, $\frac{1}{2}$ gets mapped to $3$ which is not in the codomain. Any ideas of how to deal with that?

Comment: If you map $(0,1)$ injectively to $(1,2)$, you can show that $|(0,1)| \le |(1,2) \cup (3,4)|$, then you map $(0,1)$ surjectively to $(1,4)$ to show that $|(0,1)| \ge |(1,2) \cup (3,4)|$

Comment: Just map $\frac12$ to $3/2$. If you can find a surjection from each set to the other (ignoring injectivity), then they have the same cardinality. This gives a surjection one way; the surjection the other way is straightforward.

Comment: Do you merely have to show that the cardinalities are equal, or are you supposed to describe a bijection between the two sets?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well now that I think of it, the question does ask to explicitly find a bijection between the sets. I just assumed it was the same as showing that the two sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596116/build-a-bijective-function-to-show-that-left-0-1-right-left-1-2-cu)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah, you're right, exactly the same question. I didn't notice that one when posting this question...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Define a new function $g$ via

$$g(\frac{1}{2})=f(\frac{1}{3}) \\
g(\frac{1}{3})=f(\frac{1}{4}) \\
...\\\
g(\frac{1}{n})=f(\frac{1}{n+1})$$
and 
$g(x)=f(x)$ otherwise.

Show that this $g$ works.